# Callable Statement with JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have created a stored procedure 'BookingDeletion'
Now, I am calling this procedure using a CallableStatement in the following way:

```
if (addBooking == null) {
    addBooking = "CALL BookingDeletion(?, ?, ?, ?)";
}
```

Now, if I want to use JpaRepository, and apply its methods on this procedure, how can I do it?
There is a huge number of operations in the procedure, so I cannot perform all the operations separately through jparepository.

Comment: any suggestions???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@Query` annotation with `nativeQuery` equal to `true`.

So you just have to declare a method like below in your Repository interface.

```
@Query(value = "{CALL BookingDeletion(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4)}", nativeQuery = true)
public void bookingDeletion(Object p1, Object p2, Object p3, Object p4);
```

Comment: Can I declare this method in my service implementation class?

Comment: The repository has been autowired there

Comment: No it must be in your Repository interface which extends JpaRepository

Comment: okay. If I want to remove the use of this CallableStatement completely, and use a simple query as a string, is there a way??

Comment: Is there any alternative to using CallableStatement?

Comment: Well above is an alternative abstraction layer to replace CallableStatement.

Comment: If I want to remove the use of this CallableStatement completely, and use a simple query as a string, is there a way??

Comment: ANy other , third approach?

Comment: Injection EntityManager in your service and use http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)

Comment: Out of the three methods given there, which method do I use for calling a stored procedure??

Comment: I want to remove the use of the callable statement completely

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: any suggestions??

Comment: Or are the above two methods, the only methods?